# Book about a girl who enters a fantasy land with a blue queen who stole her dog

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, isekai

I'm looking for a book I read as a kid. I remember there being a queen on the cover in a blue dress.

It was a about a girl who gets sucked into another book to get her dog back. I remember that she was with a man that was going to take her to the blue queen to get her dog, and he offered her a lemon drop that had been in his pocket for a while.

That's pretty much all I can remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[The Key to Rondo](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2272641.The_Key_to_Rondo)*** (2007) by Emily Rodda...? It's the first book in the *[Rondo](https://www.goodreads.com/series/45071-rondo)* trilogy.

> A new realm of magic from Emily Rodda, the New York Times bestselling author of the Deltora books.
>
> There are three rules to the old painted, music Wind the box three times only. Never shut the box when the music is playing. Never move the box before the music stops.
>
> Leo wouldn't dream of breaking these rules, but does his stubborn cousin Mimi listen? She winds the box four times -- and suddenly the paintings on its side come to life and a powerful witch is released. Now its up to Leo and Mimi to stop the witch, if only they can find the key to the music box -- and the magical world it controls.
>
> [image: Front cover of "The Key to Rondo" by Emily Rodda.]

From a [review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/emily-rodda/the-key-to-rondo/):

> Leo and his “least-favorite second cousin” Mimi have seen each other annually at Great-Aunt Bethany’s prim afternoon teas. **When Great-Aunt Bethany dies and leaves Leo a finely painted music box, he plans to obey its strict rules—“Turn the key three times only,” etc.—but Mimi comes to visit and immediately the music box is overwound. The tiny, delicately bold paintings on its sides come to life, springing into Leo’s bedroom. An evil queen snatches Mimi’s dog back into the music-box world, and Leo and Mimi are off in pursuit.**

From the [Google books preview](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Key_to_Rondo/nAX8kS-cpkkC?hl=en&gbpv=0) of the book itself:

> **Conker gave a last, tremednous sniff and cleared his throat noisily. "Well," he said with forced heartiness, "enough of that! Here — have a lemon drop."
>
> He felt around in his pocket and pulled out a handful of large yellow candies shaped vaguely like flattened lemons and covered with a dusting of dot crumbs and fluff.
>
> "Help yourself," he said grandly, holding the lemon drops out on the palm of his rather grubby hand.
>
> Not wanting to offend him, Leo and Mimi each took one of the dingy candies, murmuring insincere thanks.**
> "Take two!" Conker urged.
> "Oh, no. One's plenty, thanks," Leo assured him, surreptitiously rubbing the lemon drops between his fingers to get off the worst of the fluff. He would have liked to throw the thing away, but Conker was watching him eagerly. Trying not to think about the dot crumbs, he pushed the lemon drop into his mouth.
> "Delicious," he said. And it was true that the lemon drop tasted good, if rather gritty.
> "I might keep mine for later," Mimi said hastily, pushing the lemon drop deep into her pocket. "I'm not hungry at the moment."
> Leo wished he'd thought of that.